# Is this fprintf statement potentially vulnerable?

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, c

Here's the statement: `fprintf(stderr, "Some random string\n").`

Is it okay not to have a format specifier, such as %s, even though the statement doesn't take any user input? Is it still potentially exploitable? It seems like it should still at least be considered a best practice to include a format specifier. I'd appreciate some clarity on the matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The statement, as you show it, is not vulnerable to anything. However, `fprintf()` is indeed an interpreter in its own right: what it takes as format string is not just a sequence of characters; it is source code for a specific language with directives beginning with a '%' sign.

When you use your `fprintf()` function like that, sooner or later, some developer will go all generic and righteous and fanatic of internationalization, and will insist on rewriting it that way:

```
/* in some .h file */
#define MSG_EN_42   "Some random string\n"

#if LANGUAGE_IS_ENGLISH
#define MSG_42   MSG_EN_42
#endif

/* in another .c file */
fprintf(stderr, MSG_42);
```

Then, some weeks/months/years later, another developer, with little grasp of C but remarkable knowledge of German/Thaï/Klingon, will change the .h to look like this:

```
/* in some .h file */
#define MSG_EN_42   "Some random string\n"
#define MSG_KG_42   "fs'k5 f%n59 #$dsai!\n"

#if LANGUAGE_IS_ENGLISH
#define MSG_42   MSG_EN_42
#endif
#if LANGUAGE_IS_KLINGON
#define MSG_42   MSG_KG_42
#endif
```

And then trouble ensues.

(Not an actual Klingon example, by the way; using true Klingon words on the unsuspecting reader would be kind of rude. But you get the idea.)

**To void these issues**, use a format string when a format string is due. This would lead to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Some random string\n");
```

or, as a simpler solution:

```
fputs("Some random string\n", stderr);
```